# Limit numbers of lines in TextView

Tags: android, scroll, textview, lines

I have a scrollable textView, and I want to limit the number of lines displayed, however xml properties are not working :

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv_addesc"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scrollbars="vertical"
   android:maxLines="12"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
   android:textSize="15sp" />
```

the number of lines displayed is 50 and there are 900 chars in the text.

How can I limit the number of lines displayed and make it scrollable ?

Edit : I tested with 846 lines and 15824 chars, the whole text is displayed regardless of different properties set.

Edit : there was a second component besides the textView, when i removed it it worked, so I will find a workaround. Thank you !

Comment: I think there is no need to define "isScrollContainer" and "lines" in this tag. It works fine without them for me.

Comment: have you tried giving layout_width as wrap_content ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You just have to set a number of lines in your `TextView` like this:

```
android:maxLines = "10"
```

and you must also add:

```
android:minLines="1"
```

**The rest of this not necessary if you are not using scrolling**

and a property which says that this TextView should be scrollable vertically:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

And in your Java-code:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't change anything. Would it have something to do with the character limit of a textView ?

Comment: Maybe, just try to decrease the maxLines, and add alot of text. I doesn't have my enviroment available now, so its just a random guess.

Comment: Add `android:minLines="1"` too

Comment: Why did you write: "[...] you must also add: `android:minLines="1"`? Android's documentation doesn't state that both properties must be set and my app doesn't need to have `minLines` set. In what cases is it required?

Comment: Didn't worked for me, but after adding `android:ellipsize="marquee"` it's working now..

Answer (score 4):

Try using this.

```
android:maxLines="12"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

In the end it add **...** if extra text available.

You can also use

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

It will reduce extra text from end that is not like a word.

Answer (score 3):

Find your textview by id:

```
TextView myTextBox=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox);
```

Now use the setMaxLines function and assign the number of lines you require in it,say 20.

```
myTextBox.setMaxLines(20);
```

This limits your text box to show 20 lines only.

Answer (score 2):

put your text view with in scroll view and set fixed height of scroll view.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_addesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="12"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</ScrollView>
```

set properties as per your need

Comment: as the property `maxLines="12"` doesn't work, the whole text is displayed (50 lines - 900 chars)

Comment: you can remove it, it was in your code. please adjust here android:layout_height="120dip" > increase or decrease height of scroll as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="120dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_addesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="12"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

hey try setting the singleline property to false. Just see if it works.

Comment: it doesn't change anything, but even `android:singleLine="true"` doesn't work too

Comment: Dont give a static height to scrollView...give it wrap content and then add the textview to a linear or relative layout..and then you can give a static height to this layout..

Answer (score 0):

I tried as said in accepted answer and others but didn't worked for me, but after adding `android:ellipsize="marquee"` it's working now..